# MYSQL how to sort money values from cheaper to more expensive?

Tags: mysql, sorting, currency

I am fighting for hours trying to figure out how can i sort the Column PRICE from Cheaper to More expensive.

I use `decimal(5,2)`

Values are like this:

```
20.99
15.99
10.15
9.20
```

i use `CONCAT` to insert the $ infront of each value. The result is like this

```
$10.15
$15.99
$20.99
$9.20
```

Desire result is this :

```
$9.20
$10.15
$15.99
$20.99
```

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: Please mention your queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For sorting you have to use `ORDER BY` clause.

For sorting from low to high try this:

```
SELECT CONCAT("$",CAST(price AS CHAR)) AS currency
FROM tablename
ORDER BY currency
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Order by Price DESC` where `DESC` is descending order and if you want ascending use `ASC`

Answer (score 0):

```
Order by price
```

Do not order by concat, because it will then order by the alphanumeric values instead of numeric.

Answer (score 0):

Your price column must have a character **CHAR() or VARCHAR()** type rather than a numeric type. Cast it as a DECIMAL in the **ORDER BY**:

```
Select * From table ORDER BY CAST(price AS DECIMAL(10,2)) DESC
```

The real fix for this would be to change the price data type to a proper numeric type.